# How to call Fragment from my Main Activity?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, android-studio, fragment

My fragment details can't be opened. when I type a word in search and I want to see the details of the word it won't open. I don't know where the error lies. Please help me. I'm still new to Android Studio

detail fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private String value = "";
    private TextView tvWord;
    private ImageButton btnBookmark;
    private WebView tvWordTranslate;
    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private int mDicType;
   

    public DetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DetailFragment getNewInstance(String value, DBHelper dbHelper, int dicType){
        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
        fragment.value = value;
        fragment.mDBHelper = dbHelper;
        fragment.mDicType = dicType;
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detia, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        tvWord = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWord);
        tvWordTranslate = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvWordTranslate);
        btnBookmark = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBookmark);

        final Word word = mDBHelper.getWord(value, mDicType);
        tvWord.setText(word.key);
        tvWordTranslate.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, word.value,"text/html", "utf-8",null);

        Word bookmarkWord = mDBHelper.getWordFromBookmark(value);
        int isMark = bookmarkWord == null ? 0 : 1;
        btnBookmark.setTag(isMark);

        int icon = bookmarkWord == null ? R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border : R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill;
        btnBookmark.setImageResource(icon);

        btnBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                int i = (int) btnBookmark.getTag();
                if (i == 0) {
                    btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_fill);
                    btnBookmark.setTag(1);
                    mDBHelper.addBookmark(word);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    btnBookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border);
                    btnBookmark.setTag(0);
                    mDBHelper.removeBookmark(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
    
}
```

I'm trying to make a dictionary.

It's just that the word details don't work, I don't know where the error is

dictionary fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DictionaryFragment extends Fragment {

    private String value = "Hello everyone!!!";
    private FragmentListener listener;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView dicList;
    private ArrayList<String> mSource = new ArrayList<String>();

    public DictionaryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dictionary, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        dicList = view.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dicList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(mSource.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    public void resetDataSource(ArrayList<String> source){
        mSource = source;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void filterValue(String value){
        adapter.getFilter().filter(value);
        int size = adapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<size;i++){
            if (adapter.getItem(i).startsWith(value)){
                dicList.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void setOnFragmentListener(FragmentListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

main activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar; import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat; import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout; import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager; import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction; import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import android.os.Bundle; import android.text.Editable; import android.text.TextWatcher; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import android.view.WindowManager; import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class kamusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
MenuItem menuSetting;
Toolbar toolbar;

DBHelper dbHelper;

DictionaryFragment dictionaryFragment;
DetailFragment detailFragment;
BookmarkFragment bookmarkFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kamus);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);

    dictionaryFragment = new DictionaryFragment();
    bookmarkFragment = BookmarkFragment.getNewInstance(dbHelper);
    goToFragment(dictionaryFragment, true);

    dictionaryFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String value) {
            String id = Bahasa.getState(kamusActivity.this,"dic_type");
            int dicType = id == null? R.id.action_it:Integer.valueOf(id);
            goToFragment( DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value,dbHelper,dicType),false);
        }
    });
    bookmarkFragment.setOnFragmentListener(new FragmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String value) {
            String id = Bahasa.getState(kamusActivity.this,"dic_type");
            int dicType = id == null? R.id.action_it:Integer.valueOf(id);
            goToFragment( DetailFragment.getNewInstance(value,dbHelper,dicType),false);
        }
    });

    EditText edit_search = findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
    edit_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
            dictionaryFragment.filterValue(charSequence.toString());
        }
        
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){
           
        }
    });

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    menuSetting = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);

    String id = Bahasa.getState(this,"dic_type");
    if (id != null)
        onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(Integer.valueOf(id)));
    else {
        ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(R.id.action_it);
        dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_it) {
        Bahasa.saveState(this,"dic_type", String.valueOf(id));
        ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
        dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
        menuSetting.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_bibt_2));
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.action_ti){
        Bahasa.saveState(this,"dic_type", String.valueOf(id));
        ArrayList<String> source = dbHelper.getWord(id);
        dictionaryFragment.resetDataSource(source);
        menuSetting.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_btbi_2));
        return true;
    }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_bookmark){
        String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
        if(!activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
            goToFragment(bookmarkFragment, false);
        }
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

void goToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isTop){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    if (!isTop)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    String activeFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container).getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (activeFragment.equals(BookmarkFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
        menuSetting.setVisible(false);
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        toolbar.setTitle("Bookmark");
    }else {
        menuSetting.setVisible(true);
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edit_search).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
    }
    return true;
}
```

}`